# how can I set or change to x-axis from financial year April to March next year in line chart

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I can able to set x axis from Jan-Dec. But I need to show data from Financial Year April to March next Year.
How to do that.Please help.

```
 var myLineChart = new Chart($("#myChart"), {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: data,
                    options: {
                   scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'CONSUMPTION IN MUs ----->'
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{                                                
                            type: "time",
                            time: {
                                format: 'MMM DD',
                                unit: 'month',
                                unitStepSize: 1,
                                displayFormats: {
                                    'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                                    'second': 'MMM DD',
                                    'minute': 'MMM DD',
                                    'hour': 'MMM DD',
                                    'day': 'MMM DD',
                                    'week': 'MMM DD',
                                    'month': 'MMM DD',
                                    'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                                    'year': 'MMM DD',

                                },
                                min: 'Apr',                              
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {                              
                                labelString: 'MONTHS ----->'                                
                            },
                            scaleOverride: true,
                            scaleShowLabels: true
                           }],
                    },
});
 window.myLine = myLineChart;
```

Comment: How do you try to do this?

Comment: Does your data include values for "April to March of next year"?  Or are you just trying to show these months on the axis?